# Getting the same order in ragged arrays in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I have two ragged arrays `Ii0` and `Iv0`. I sort the values according to increasing `j` which `Ii01` shows but then I want `Iv01` to reflect the same sorting order. In general, I want the code to be able to handle many different shapes of `Ii0` and `Iv0`. The current and desired outputs are attached.

```
import numpy as np

Ii0=np.array([[[0, 1],
        [0, 3],
        [1, 2]],
                 [[0, 3],
                  [2,5],
                  [0, 1]]])  

Iv0 = np.array([[[10],
                 [20],
                 [30]],
                        [[100],
                         [200],
                         [300]]])

Ii01 = np.array([sorted(i, key = lambda x : x[1]) for i in Ii0])
print("Ii01  =",Ii01)
Iv01 = np.array([sorted(i, key = lambda x : x[0]) for i in Iv0])
print("Iv01  =",Iv01)
```

The current output is

```
Ii01  = [array([[[0, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [0, 3]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 3],
        [2, 5]]])]
Iv01  = [array([[[ 10],
        [ 20],
        [ 30]],

       [[100],
        [200],
        [300]]])]
```

The expected output is

```
Ii01  = [array([[[0, 1],
        [1, 2],
        [0, 3]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 3],
        [2, 5]]])]
Iv01  = [array([[[ 10],
        [ 30],
        [ 20]],

       [[300],
        [100],
        [200]]])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np

Ii0 = np.array([[
    [0, 1],
    [0, 3],
    [1, 2]],
    [[0, 3],
     [2, 5],
     [0, 1]]])

Iv0 = np.array([[[10],
                 [20],
                 [30]],
                [[100],
                 [200],
                 [300]]])

Ii01 = np.array([Ii[np.argsort(Ii[:, 1])] for Ii in Ii0])
print("Ii01  =", Ii01)
Iv01 = np.array([Iv[np.argsort(Ii[:, 1])] for Ii,Iv in zip(Ii0,Iv0)])
print("Iv01  =", Iv01)
```

we need to sort our first array with `np.argsort` which basically return index of sorted array and that indices we used to arrange second array (actually second array is not sorted, it rearranges passions based on first array sort)

Comment: Is there a more generic way to do it? If I change the nature of ```Ii0```, I get the error: ```TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple```.

Comment: It depends on the shape of the array … You can play around with `np.argsort`

Comment: If I have ```Ii0 = np.array([[
    [0, 1],
    [0, 3],
    [1, 2]],
            [[0, 3],
             [2, 5],
             [0, 1]],
                     [[0, 3],
                      [2, 5],
                      [0, 1],
                      [1, 4]]])```. It doesn't seem to work for this.

Comment: it seems like you enter list of lists or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes in your case 3,3,4 element respectively, which is not work with this case

Comment: That's right. It would be great if the code can handle random shapes. For instance, ```(3,3,4,5,10,3,20,11...)```